# Python - How to send values between functions once

Tags: python, function, return

So I am trying to create a script where I have two function where the first function I send a requests and save two values and the second function is where I apply it as a json. Before I continue my issue I would like to add my code:

```
def get_info(thread):


    url = thread #Whatever site such as Google.com

    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    }

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=12)

    bs4 = soup(r.text, "html.parser") #We scrape here


    try:
        search = bs4.find('h1').text
    except:
        search = None

    try:
        image = bs4.find('image')
    except:
        image = None

    #I want to use the search and image on the function below

    --------------------------------------------------------- #Here is where I want to cut

def get_json(): 

    url = thread + '.json' #We just add json at the end to get the website that supports json

    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    }

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=12)

    json_resp = r.json()

    for i in json_resp:
       if search in i['search']: #I use the 'search = bs4.find('h1').text' to match and only want to print if it matches
           print(i)

    try:
        final_name = i['name']
    except:
        final_name = None

    try:
        final_img = i['image']
    except:
        final_img = None

    metadata = {
        'name': final_name,
        'image': final_img

    }
return metadata #return the value
```

There is two function `get_info` and `get_json`- What I want to do is that when I run the code:

```
while True:
    testing = get_json(thread)
    print(testing)
    time.sleep(5)
```

an output should be `return of get_json` - However the issue I am having is that I want to only call `get_json(thread)` but to be able to get a return of `get_json(thread)` I need to get the value of *search* from `get_info(thread)`*only ONCE (its the same all the time)* to be ablet o continue to run the **get_json(thread)**

My question is: How can I be able to call `get_json(thread)` without needing to call `get_info(thread)` for everytime I call `get_json(thread)` (To gain the *search* value from `get_info(thread)` only once and use it everytime I call get_json)

Comment: May be I did not understand your question properly. But, if ```get_info()``` return value does not change, you could call it once before entering while loop and pass the return value of ```get_info()``` as a parameter to ```get_json()``` along with ```thread```.

Comment: Oh you might be actually right, you mean like inside the while loop when calling testing?

Comment: You need call inside if ```get_info()``` output changes every 5sec. If it does not change, just call it "outside" while loop.

Comment: Oh dangit! You are right. I totally forgot about this way! haha @MohanaRao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `get_info()` return value does not change, you could call it once before entering while loop and pass the return value of `get_info()` as a parameter to `get_json()` along with `thread`